# python plot error when reading .csv with pandas: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, csv, pandas, plot

I am trying to read few .csv files and do something line plot(x,y) with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

colnames = ['X','Y']

xfmr_x_y_file = pandas.read_csv('AMI_X_Y.csv', names=colnames)
gnode_x_y_file = pandas.read_csv('AMI_GNODE_X_Y.csv', names=colnames)
node_x_y_file = pandas.read_csv('AMI_NODE_X_Y.csv', names=colnames)

EX_XFMR_X_meas = (xfmr_x_y_file.X)
EX_XFMR_Y_meas = (xfmr_x_y_file.Y)
DB_GNODE_X_meas = (gnode_x_y_file.X)
DB_GNODE_Y_meas = (gnode_x_y_file.Y)
DB_NODE_X_meas = (node_x_y_file.X)
DB_NODE_Y_meas = (node_x_y_file.Y)

plt.plot(EX_XFMR_X_meas[1:],EX_XFMR_Y_meas[1:],label='XFMR')
plt.title('TUR117')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(18, 6)
#plt.savefig('TUR117.png')#,dpi=300
plt.show()
```

But it is generating a weird error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-0428c97a1c49> in <module>()
     17 DB_NODE_Y_meas = (node_x_y_file.Y)
     18 
---> 19 plt.plot(EX_XFMR_X_meas[1:],EX_XFMR_Y_meas[1:],label='XFMR')
     20 plt.title('TUR117')
     21 plt.xlabel('X')

C:\Program Files (x86)\ActivePython 2.7.8\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.pyc in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   2985         ax.hold(hold)
   2986     try:
-> 2987         ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
   2988         draw_if_interactive()
   2989     finally:

C:\Program Files (x86)\ActivePython 2.7.8\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.pyc in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   4135         lines = []
   4136 
-> 4137         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
   4138             self.add_line(line)
   4139             lines.append(line)

C:\Program Files (x86)\ActivePython 2.7.8\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.pyc in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
    315                 return
    316             if len(remaining) <= 3:
--> 317                 for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
    318                     yield seg
    319                 return

C:\Program Files (x86)\ActivePython 2.7.8\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.pyc in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    274         ret = []
    275         if len(tup) > 1 and is_string_like(tup[-1]):
--> 276             linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])
    277             tup = tup[:-1]
    278         elif len(tup) == 3:

C:\Program Files (x86)\ActivePython 2.7.8\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.pyc in _process_plot_format(fmt)
     97     # handle the multi char special cases and strip them from the
     98     # string
---> 99     if fmt.find('--') >= 0:
    100         linestyle = '--'
    101         fmt = fmt.replace('--', '')

C:\Program Files (x86)\ActivePython 2.7.8\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   1934                 return self[name]
   1935             raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" %
-> 1936                                  (type(self).__name__, name))
   1937 
   1938     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'
```

If I simply do `plt.plot(EX_XFMR_X[1:])`, it plots fine and it appears that for some reason it is not able to simulate `plt.plot(x,y)` format. Did anyone face this problem before? Is there something I am not doing right?

Comment: It may be an issue with your input. Generate the Series manually and test.

Comment: @bejota can you please elaborate on your comment?

Comment: You're using input that we cannot access. Begin with a simple example and see if you can reproduce the problem. For example: `EX_XFMR_X_meas = range(10)`.

Comment: bejota. I had the same problem. You should try transform your "pandas.Series" to list.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the `plt.plot(x,y)` is indeed not respected in this case. Now both your inputs `EX_XFMR_X_meas[1:]` and `EX_XFMR_Y_meas[1:]` are still pandas.Series, so `plt.plot(x,y)` takes the Series' index as `x` and the Series' values as `y`. If the values of the first variable depict the `x` and the second the `y`, do:

```
plt.plot(EX_XFMR_X_meas[1:].values,EX_XFMR_Y_meas[1:].values,label='XFMR')
```

which passes them as `numpy.ndarray` .

I guess the weird error originates because `plt.plot()` does not know what to do with the second `pandas.Series` as input.